# Issues getting google sheets script to repeat for multiple data and then clear cells

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my [Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h5XyqtVC3Rpco3V9PF0LhvTU39yWiTzcgumyOzm4igU/edit?usp=sharing) which I refer to below.

My sheet is designed to track skill level changes in a game as people play matches against each other. My sheet "Team Picker" allows you to specify who was on each team and input the score, and it will output an updated skill rating (ELO) in column P.

I have set up a button which currently works to submit all the data I want for the player at G4. I haven't been able to work out how to repeat this to submit data for any other selected players. As there are not always 6 people on a team I would also ideally like the script to recognise if no data has been input so that it doesn't copy over blank values.

I would then like to clear the values between G4:G9, G15:G20 and M11:M12 and increase the value of cell M2 by 1. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

### Approach

In cases like this I would recommend to create configuration variables that will store the reference to your cells. This way it will be easier to extend or modify the script behavior based on the Spreadsheet structure. Using Javascript object is really easy to create a configuration variable for each team.

```
var team1 = {start: 4, end: 9, player: "G", oldElo: "H", newElo: "P", result: "N11"};
var team2 = {start: 15, end: 20, player: "G", oldElo: "H", newElo: "P", result: "N12"};
```

In this way you don't have to worry about the cell references when building the export logic.

Now you should proceed to export the needed info. Since the structure for a team is almost the same I would suggest to build another function that will return an array with the extracted information:

```
function fillTeamRows(ss, team) {
    // These are general configuration variables that are the same for every team.
    var match = "M2";
    var date = "M5";
    var scoreboard1 = "M11";
    var scoreboard2 = "M12";

    // Here i declare an empty array that I will fill according to the export logic
    var teamRows = [];
    var i;
    for (i=team.start; i<= team.end; i++) { // I will loop through the team range to build my export
      if (!ss.getRange(`${team.player}${i}`).getValue() == "") { // If there is no player in this row, skip it.
        var playerRow = [];
        playerRow.push(ss.getRange(match).getValue());
        playerRow.push(ss.getRange(`${team.player}${i}`).getValue());
        playerRow.push(ss.getRange(date).getValue());
        playerRow.push(ss.getRange(team.result).getValue());
        playerRow.push(ss.getRange(`${team.oldElo}${i}`).getValue());
        playerRow.push(ss.getRange(`${team.newElo}${i}`).getValue());
        playerRow.push(ss.getRange(scoreboard1).getValue());
        playerRow.push(ss.getRange(scoreboard2).getValue());
        teamRows.push(playerRow); // Add the player row to the team array.
        // Now you can clear the information about the player
        ss.getRange(`${team.player}${i}`).clear();
      }
    }
   return teamRows;
}
```

Now I would use this function to build the export for the two teams and export the data on the

```
  let team1Rows = fillTeamRows(formSS, team1);
  let team2Rows = fillTeamRows(formSS, team2);

  // Now it's a good moment to clear the scoreboard and increment the match counter.
  formSS.getRange("M11:M12").clear(); //clear
  
  formSS.getRange("M2").setValue(1 +formSS.getRange("M2").getValue()); //increment
  
  //Input Values
  var values = [...team1Rows,...team2Rows];
  
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, values.length, 8).setValues(values);
```